# mulesoft dataweave arrayindexoutofbounds error

Tags: mule

I have a simple flow that reads a csv file using a File Connector and I am trying to transform that data to json. Does not matter what I put as expression, I am always getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at design time and the preview does not generate. Below is the flow:

```
    <flow name="dw_exampleFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\BNA\dw_sample" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="application/csv" doc:name="File"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="3496b3e4-708e-49c3-9f87-764eb149d1ee">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/dw
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Below is the error I am getting:
[Design Time Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN7l8.jpg)

Comment: on a side note, may not be related to your issue but I think output type you want is json `%output application/json`

Comment: I tried that too, but getting the same error. So I wanted to try first with the dataweave canonical object and see if that works...

Answer (score 0):

What mule runtime are you using? it's working on me using 3.7.3

[image]
[image]

```
<flow name="Flow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint
            path="/work/demo/workspace/3.7.3-dataweave/src/main/resources/input"
            moveToDirectory="/work/demo/workspace/3.7.3-dataweave/src/main/resources/output"
            responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" />
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="ff8bbc88-efc7-4952-816a-a13f00ef6e6d"
            doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer
            doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </flow>
```

Comment: hmm...I am using 3.7.3 too, EE edition though. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: It looks more like a design time Anypoint issue. I ran the flow and it works fine. Which Anypoint studio version do you have? Mine is 5.4.0

Comment: I'm using the same version, did you download it or use update? I've read it's  advisable to download instead of update.

Comment: I updated it. Probably that explains. Thanks for the input.